# Is it possible to use decltype to figure out the return type of a member function of a forward declared template class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class which I have forward declared and I would like to be able to figure out the return type of a member function of that class in a header file which doesn't have access to the definition. Can I do something like this while only including forward declerations in my header? An example that works if the header has access to the definition is below, but I would like to avoid including the definitions in my header files:

```
// file name Matrix.hpp
#include<utility>
#include "array.hpp" // I would like to remove this include

template<typename T, unsigned int N>
class Array;

using MatrixD = Array<double, 2>; 
using return_type = decltype(std::decval<MatrixD>().operator()("i,j"));

class Array_User{
public:
    virtual return_type Array_op(const std::string);
    ... Rest of class 
};
```

Comment: Without a definition, how is the compiler supposed to figure out whether `operator()` exists, let alone what it returns?

Comment: Sorry I just read that you don't have the definition at all. Not possible. I agree with the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward declared means that you know that the class (or class template) **exists**, not what it **contains**. From this, it's obviously impossible to get information about any members, including member functions.

Comment: I understand now, on a slightly related note, is there a way to have a dummy return type which will get defined in the Derived class? The derived class will have MatrixD members and so needs to include the header anyway.

Comment: @quadruplebond It depends on what you mean by "dummy return type". Of course you could use a forward-declared return type in the header if you use of it doesn't require it to be complete, but that usually means returning a pointer, not an instance of that type. Returning an instance requires the type to be complete as the caller needs to know the size to provide a return slot, a forward-declared type does not (yet) know its size until it gets completed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I used to have the return type forward declared, but due to a library change, it will be difficult to do that, which is why I am using decval and decltype to deduce the type instead.

Answer (score 1):

No. The type must be complete and known at that moment.